# How to make vue js ssr using the django framework

Tags: django, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I want to make some part of my application capable of supporting server rendering. In the project, we actively use vuex and vue router.

We receive all data using api requests

Tell me where to go or provide any working code snippet.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you precise your needs? For SSR using Vue consider Nuxt.

Comment: @Aurélien We not using Nuxt. Is this your easiest way?

Comment: A nice setup can be Django Rest Framework for you backend/API and Nuxt to make the SSR rendering.

Comment: But we have a lot of old code that works properly. Nuxt and djandgo will not work on the same port, I suppose. Perhaps we can run 2 servers in parallel on different ports, for example, Nuxt on port 8080. But in this case rendering will be very slow since 2 servers will play ping pong from requests

Comment: Why two backend guys? I don't really think we need that.

Answer (score 0):

An example of an answer might be this. You are creating a fully isolated SPA application with SSR. Django acts only as an API for your application (including you will need to receive data for INITIAL_STATE by API). Next, you start your NodeJs server on any port. Next, you need to configure nginx for redirect requests from port 80 for specific routes to the port of your application.

This is just a theory. Until hands reached a full-fledged example